# Servers: about Weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, java-6

From where to take Oracle Weblogic 12.1.1 because I can't find it on google and I can't find it even on Oracle site to take it.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/wls/1213/wls1213_dev_update3.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can try on https://edelivery.oracle.com/ , you will require oracle support credentials.